# SQL запрос через phpMyAdmin выдаёт ошибку

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Мне нужно в строках таблиц БД удалить символы:
        `;;` `;quot;`

Делаю SQL запросы через phpMyAdmin:

```
    `UPDATE tablitsa SET stolbets = REPLACE(stolbets, '&amp;quot;', '');`
    `UPDATE tablitsa SET stolbets = REPLACE(stolbets, ';;', '');`
```

Выдаёт ошибки:

> "#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой
>   версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около ''&amp)' на
>   строке 1" "#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по
>   используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '')'
>   на строке 1"

Версия MySQL: 5.7.21-20

Экранирование не помогает.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У меня ваш запрос отлично отрабатывает. Смотрите через что вы выполняете запрос, это средство похоже заменяет некоторые символы при приеме. потому как никакого `&amp` о котором сообщается в ошибке в запросах у вас нет, а БД это получила ...

Comment: Извиняюсь! Неправильно оформил пост. Теперь всё точно.

Comment: Запрос делаю через стандартный phpMyAdmin на хосте.

Comment: Но вот этот http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebc51d/2 пример показывает, что запрос отлично выполняется. в тексте запроса в любом случае отсутствует закрывающаяся скобка сразу после `&amp`. А в тексте ошибки неоднозначно сказано, что ошибка найдена именно около текста `&amp)`, а значит текст в MySQL что то передало не так, как вы пишите.

Comment: Mike, обычные символы заменяются без проблем. Проблема с точкой запятой и &. Как их правильно скормить мускулю - непонятно.

Comment: Виноват не MySQL, а ваше средство, которым вы выполняете запрос. с консоли запустите mysql и передайте запрос. или напишите скрипт на любом языке, который передаст этот запрос MySQL. Или подключитесь к БД нормальным средством, например MySQL Workbench. А  phpmyadmin всю жизнь был одним из самых глючных средств работы с БД

Answer (score 1):

Пока ждал ответов, покопался в функциях, потестил, и нашёл вариант )

```
`UPDATE `tablitsa` SET `title` = REPLACE(`title`, ';;', '') WHERE `title` LIKE '%;;%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`
```